# What is the Intel FPGA configuration file .pof used for, and how is it different from the file .jic?

Tags: intel-fpga, configuration

The Intel FPGAs have a number of different programming files, among these the files:

- .pof (Programmer Object File)
- .jic (JTAG Indirect Configuration)

I know that the file .jic can be used to program a configuration flash on the FPGA with the configuration image, so the FPGA can automatically load the configuration from flash at next power on.

It appears that the file .pof can be used for something similar, though I can't find the details.

What is the file .pof used for, and how is it different from the file .jic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JTAG Indirect Configuration (JIC) file carries the SRAM Object File (SOF) data plus JTAG metadata.

This is for loading directly into the FPGA's Configuration RAM (CRAM) and carries the FPGA configuration file.

The Programmer Output File (POF) carries the programming data for the actual Flash EPROM (FEPROM) that the FPGA will load configuration files from. Some FPGAs can select between multiple files.

So the POF is what gets programmed into the board's FPGA FEPROM during development, manufacturing or update. All in one single file.

And the POF can contain one or more configuration files plus any user data occupying the spare FEPROM space. This could be software or data for an FPGA internal CPU or anything. The POF can be as large as the whole FEPROM or as small as one configuration file. The Programmer software lets you build a POF with what you want in it, pulling in other files like SOF(s) as necessary.

The JIC, meanwhile, can carry only one configuration file, same as a SOF.